# Mute Flash in Google Chrome Mac OS X (or just mute any app in Mac OS X)

Tags: mac, google-chrome, flash, google-chrome-extensions, mute

Is this possible using an extension for chrome or using a 3rd party app?

Comment: Do you want to just mute flash when using chrome?

Comment: Yes only Flash in Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the chrome toolbox extension won't mute for mac yet.  Not sure why and would love an explanation/rebuttal by someone who can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This [chrome toolbox extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn) allows you to mute tabs.

Do the following:

Install the extension. It will show a small icon (with an m) in the top right of your browser. Click that, and you are given an option to **mute all tabs**. Alt+w is the shortcut.

Comment: How do I mute a tab using that?

Comment: Install it.  It will show a small icon in the top right of your browser.  Click that, and you are given an option to mute all tabs.  Alt+w is the shortcut.   Works fine for me.

Comment: @Tyilo Let me know does it work for you...

Comment: No option to do that: http://cl.ly/7Lku

Comment: @Tyilo You can mute all tabs.  Not just a specific tab.

Comment: This doesn’t work on Macs and is irrelevant at this place.

Comment: This doesn't work on mac